# Is there an efficient way to compute the sum of all elements of a matrix product?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have two matricies $A$ and $B$, each $N \times K$ with $N >> K$. I need the sum of all elements in $AB^T$, and am currently computing this sum directly, which takes $O(N^2 \cdot K)$ operations. It seems plausible that there is a much more efficient way to compute the same value, since I only have $O(N \cdot K)$ inputs and a single output. Is there a known algorithm for computing or approximating the sum with less than $N^2$ operations?

In case the details matter, in my case K is 64 and N is ~1,000,000

Comment: By summing all elements of $AB^T$, do you mean $\sum (AB^T)_{ij} = \sum a_{ik}b_{jk}$?
If yes, compute two $1 \times K$ row vectors and take dot product between them: $\sum a_{ik}b_{jk} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^K \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^N a_{ik}\right)\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^N b_{jk} \right)$

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for